# How to convert Expression<TValue> into Expression<Object>

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

#### How do you convert `Expression<Func<TViewModel, TValue>>` into `Expression<Func<TViewModel, Object>>`?

I have a function:

```
static Expression<Func<TViewModel, object>> Convert<TViewModel,TValue>(Expression<Func<TViewModel, TValue>> expr)
{
   var param = expr.Parameters[0];
   Expression body = expr.Body;
   return Expression.Lambda<Func<TViewModel, object>>(body, param);
}
```

It works for reference types (`string`) conversions but value types (`DateTime`) it throws run-time exception on the return statement:

> Expression of type 'System.DateTime' cannot be used for return type 'System.Object'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to box the value type in order to return a value type as object. `Convert` method can do this for you.

```
static Expression<Func<TViewModel, object>> Convert<TViewModel, TValue>(Expression<Func<TViewModel, TValue>> expr)
{
    var param = expr.Parameters[0];
    Expression body = expr.Body;
    var convert = Expression.Convert(body, typeof(object));
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TViewModel, object>>(convert, param);
}
```

Also you said for basic types `(string, int)` it works. It wouldn't have worked for `int` as it is a value type.

Comment: Sorry, only tested with strings, but assumed int would work the same. Thanks for the answer! I fixed the question, thanks for the additional insight.